# Ubuntu with both 32bit and 64bit libcurl

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, curl

Im running a c++ application and Asterisk in 64bit Ubuntu machine.My C++ application needs 32bit libcurl. And Asterisk needs 64bit libcurl to do some http calls in the dialpaln.Can I keep both 32bit and 64bit libcurl in the same machine and config asterisk to lookup for 64bit libcurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the C++ application is something you've linked and installed yourself (eg in `/usr/local/...`) and Asterisk is from the Ubuntu repositories, they shouldn't interfere with each other anyway.

Asterisk will used the 64-bit shared libraries it would have otherwise, and you compile your own libcurl and link it in with your 32-bit app - whether you do this statically or not, as everything will be under the `/usr/local/...` hierarchy.

It is possible to have both 64- and 32- bit copies of shared libraries installed in Ubuntu - Ubuntu's ability to do this is called multi-arch.  But I don't think that's really relevant here because you're compiling and linking your own application so you can link with your own local copy of whichever libraries you need to.